# How can I change spark ui port?

Tags: apache-spark

I have installed spark on a cluster, and I have marathon too, both are in the port 8080, How can I change the spark-ui default port?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html:

> You can optionally configure the cluster further by setting environment variables in conf/spark-env.sh. Create this file by starting with the conf/spark-env.sh.template, and copy it to all your worker machines for the settings to take effect. The following settings are available:
>
> ...
>
> SPARK_MASTER_WEBUI_PORT - Port for the master web UI (default: 8080).

So - copy `conf/spark-env.sh.template` to `conf/spark-env.sh`, and edit it to include: `SPARK_MASTER_WEBUI_PORT=<your preferred port>`

Answer (score 8):

just add a --webui-port argument when starting the master

```
/sbin/start-master.sh --webui-port PORT
```

alternatively you can define your clusters settings in a config file:
create a copy of *conf/spark-env.sh.template* as *conf/spark-env.sh* 
and add your settings there:
the one you need now is SPARK_MASTER_WEBUI_PORT=PORT

Comment: But I started all the cluster using $SPARK_HOME/sbin/start-all.sh any idea? @daniel-b

Comment: @Asier `SPARK_MASTER_WEBUI_PORT=8082 $SPARK_HOME/sbin/start-all.sh`

Comment: @Asier added a followup to the answer